# Include and ThenInclude Performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have an EFCore query with takes > 80 seconds. I read on the internet that using "Include" massively in a single query is a bad idea, because EFCore creates a very complex SQL String.

As suggested several times on the internet, i have started to split my big single query in smaller pieces.

Unfortunately, most of the examples on the internet were very simple. No case of using ThenInclude. Anyone have an idea what I can do to reduce the calls for "ThenInclude" or rewrite in an other way?

In this version the query is still very slow:

```
public async Task<List<TblAppointment>> GetAppointments(System.Guid activityId, System.Guid? categoryOrgId)
{
    var query = _context.TblAppointment
        .Join(_context.TblTour, appointment => appointment.ApmPkId, tour => tour.TouId, (appointment, tour) => new { appointment, tour })
        .Where(find => !find.appointment.ApmDDeleted.HasValue && find.tour.TouOrgId.HasValue && find.tour.TouOrgId.Value == activityId)
        .Select(select => select.appointment);

    await query.Include(include => include.TblAppointmentQuestionnaireResult)
        .ThenInclude(include => include.TblAppointmentQuestionnaireResultAnswer)
        .ThenInclude(include => include.TblAppointmentQuestionnaireResultAnswerHistory)
        .LoadAsync();

    await query.Include(include => include.TblAppointmentQuestionnaireResult)
        .ThenInclude(include => include.TblAppointmentQuestionnaireResultAnswer)
        .ThenInclude(include => include.ApmqstrsanQstgrqs)
        .ThenInclude(include => include.QstgrqsLst)
        .ThenInclude(include => include.TblListEntry)
        .LoadAsync();

    await query.Include(include => include.TblAppointmentStatus)
        .ThenInclude(include => include.ApmstaSta)
        .LoadAsync();

    await query.Include(include => include.TblAppointmentAssignment)
        .ThenInclude(include => include.ApmassOrg)
        .LoadAsync();

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would use SQL Server Profiler to see the bottlenecks. Since your user name indicates that you are from Germany, too, you may want to take a look at [my forum article about using SQL Server Profiler](https://entwicklergate.de/t/performance-tuning-langsamer-sql-abfragen/374?u=uwekeim).

Comment: Are you sure that you have to use ThenInclude? I don't know if I get it right, but depending on the examples on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-2.1 it looks like, you only need this, when querying information about the object that is RESULTING from the previous query.

Since I don't know about your database you may wanna try to change the ThenInclude to Inculde. I don't know if this is correct in your context.

Comment: Also, if you want to improve your database speed, you can index your tables on columns, which are query very often. In your case maybe the appointment.ApmDDeleted or tour.TouOrgId

Comment: *I read on the internet that using "Include" massively in a single query is a bad idea, because EFCore creates a very complex SQL String* Where did you read that? It applies to EF6, but EF Core uses multiple simpler queries, so you don't need to do that manually.

Comment: @IvanStoev there's a warning here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data "Since version 3.0.0 [of EF core], each Include ... can significantly change the performance of your queries, for better or worse"

Comment: Not knowing your DbContext structure this will be of limited use, but...

I had a similar situation and got from O(10sec) to O(0.1sec) by doing the subsequent queries from the join tables (is that their name?), which map the id of a `TblAppointment` to the id of one or more `TblAppointmentQuestionnaireResult` entries, rather than from `TblAppointment` itself.

This isn't exact, but something like `var qr = _context.TblAppointmentQuestionnaireResult.Where(r => r.Something == query.Something).Include(...).ThenInclude(...).ToList();` and assigning `query.Something = qr;`

Comment: @mrblewog Yeah, that was at the time of writing, before 3.0 where they totally changed everything, so now it has the same problems as EF6.